# Why this Django Rest Framework simple serializer don't work with ViewSet?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have to endpoints with Django REST: `ProductViewSet` and `DeviceViewSet`. They are as simple as a `GET` method with `retrieve` and `list`.

While I was profiling, I did a bit of research and I decided to write my own very simple serializers (not from DRF) and the performance is highly improved.

The `ProductViewSet` works perfectly for `retrieve` and `list` methods.

The `DeviceViewSet` works for `list` but fails for `retrieve` because of the serializer.

This is the error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/everton/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/everton/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/everton/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/everton/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 106, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/everton/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 70, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "/home/everton/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 723, in render
    context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
  File "/home/everton/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 655, in get_context
    raw_data_put_form = self.get_raw_data_form(data, view, 'PUT', request)
  File "/home/everton/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 551, in get_raw_data_form
    serializer = view.get_serializer(instance=instance)
  File "/home/everton/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 110, in get_serializer
    return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'
```

Everything is nearly identical excel the `DeviceSerializer` uses the `ProductSerializer` because of a ForeignKey field. I can't seem to find the issue, any thoughts?

I already tried to overwrite the methods `get_serializer` and `get_serializer_class` and after setting a breakpoint right before the response is returned, the serialized data is ok, the error happens when the response is returned.

```py
class DeviceViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Device.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DeviceSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        device = get_object_or_404(self.get_queryset(), id=pk)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(device)
        return Response(data=serializer.data)

    def list(self, request):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=qs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        product = get_object_or_404(self.get_queryset(), id=pk)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(product)
        return Response(data=serializer.data)

    def list(self, request):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=qs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

```py
class DeviceSerializer(object):
    """
    Serializer for one or more device(s)
    """

    product = ProductSerializer

    def __init__(self, entries, many=False):
        self.many = many
        self.entries = entries if self.many else [entries]

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self.serializer_data(self.entries)

    def serializer_data(self, entries):

        serialized = [
            {
                "id": obj.id,
                "name": obj.name,
                'description': obj.description,
                'product': self.product(obj.product).data,
            } for obj in entries
        ]

        return serialized if self.many else serialized[0]


class ProductSerializer(object):
    """
    Main serializer for products
    """

    def __init__(self, entries, many=False, fields=None, exclude=None):
        self.many = many
        self.entries = entries if self.many else [entries]

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self.serializer_data(self.entries)

    def serializer_data(self, entries):
        serialized = [
            {
                "id": obj.id,
                "productName": obj.product_name,
                "productType": obj.product_type,
                "productSeries": obj.product_series,
            } for obj in entries
        ]

        return serialized if self.many else serialized[0]
```

Comment: Can you please provide the *full* traceback?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem added!

Comment: The error originates in the `views.py` file, in the function/method `get_serializer`. Neither of those is shown in the question.

Comment: @9769953 that error came when I tried to overwrite the `get_serializer` method. The traceback is not updated

Comment: Shouldn't your serializers inherit from the `Serializer` (or `ModelSerializer`) class.

Comment: The idea is to not use the serializers from DRF to improve the performance

Comment: How does DRF's serializers affect the performance?

Comment: @Josewails for simple use cases (GET) where the full capability of DRF's serializers is not used but you still have heavy responses, DRF's serializers are just a bunch of unnecessary function calls. Again, for simple use cases . See: https://www.toptal.com/python/performance-optimization-testing-django